# Abbreviation for "announcement"?

Tags: nouns, abbreviations

Is there a common abbreviation for "announcement"?

If there is, what is it?

Comment: And why would the EL&U system not let me submit the two questions as a single paragraph, but it would let me submit them as two, single-sentence paragraphs?

Comment: If you terminate a line with two spaces, and then go new line, then you get two lines in the same paragraph (w/o the empty line, I mean).

Comment: @gd1 - I know _howS to format text within the question field.  My comment was inquiring _why_ I had to put each sentence into its own paragraph to submit the question.  When I had a single paragraph, with the same two sentences you see above, the EL&U system would NOT let me submit it as a question.

Comment: @Theta30 - _want_ -- not really, but the job I'm applying for has so many different numbers (e.g., a job number, a job id, an announcement number, a control number, and on and on) and I really didn't want multiple lines. I can't control the length of the actual numbers, but I can control how I reference the numbers (e.g., "Job #" instead of "Job Number:"). I had minimized everything as much as I could, except the word "announcement" and the line was still wrapping.

Comment: @A Lion: sorry, I misunderstood. Was just trying to help...

Comment: @gd1 - No sweat.  I'm just still curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen "ann." used a lot in subject lines on mailing lists. I'm not sure if it's widely used in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

The most common, seems to be "anncmnt".

From the [abbreviations dictionary](http://www.abbreviations.com/bs.aspx?st=ANNOUNCEMENT&SE=2)

and another [forum](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_abbreviate_the_word_announcement)

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can just put, `Ann.` for Announcement.

Also, I think that you may use `TBA` (To be announced / advised) if you would like to indicate a status.

Answer (score 0):

The abbreviation for announcement would likely depend on the type of announcement concerned.

A party or other social event might use RSVP, as might baby showers or wedding showers (in the US). An invitation to a different type of event, such as a recital, might include something similar.

Wedding invitations (or save the date announcements) will usually include some variation of "Announcing the wedding of [A] and [B]." A birth announcement will usually include some variation of "Announcing the arrival [or birth] of [Baby]."

The best answer, I think, is that it depends on what you are announcing. I'd consult examples of other texts similar to whatever you'd need to produce.

Comment: It's for a job announcement.  All of my googling and duckduckgoing have found lots of employment related abbreviations, but not an actual abbreviation for the word "announcement" :(

Comment: This is not for your particular use _A Lion_ but **“PSA” (Personal Service Announcement)** is a very common abbreviation.  I'll include it on this page because searching for “abbreviation for announcement” ends up here, and would have helped me out a week ago when I really needed it.  So for posterity!

Answer (score -1):

The best abbreviation for “announcement” is usually “message”.

Comment: First off, welcome to English.se. *Announcements* are not identical to *messages*.